# ws jaxb custom external mapping

Tags: binding, wsdl, jaxb, wsimport

I have to do custom JAXB external mapping file.
Already red [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html) about this and can not find any suitable example of JAXB customization. My scenario is that I have two WSDL files main WSDL and secondary WSDL which is included in main one. And in secondary WSDL file is one `complexType` definition which has a name that I want to customize. BTW name of that complexType is `objectFactory`. So now you know what I really really need that external customization.

I have came so far that when I run  `wsimport path-to-my-main-wsdl -b customBindings.jaxb`
output is like

```
[ERROR] XPath evaluation of "//xs:complexType[@name='objectFactory']" results in empty target node
line 2 of file:/customBindings.jaxb
```

File `customBindings.jaxb` looks like

```
<jxb:bindings version="1.0" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="path-to-my-secondary-wsdl#types?schema1" node="//xs:complexType[@name='objectFactory']">
        <jxb:class name="MyObjectFactory" />
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

At second line of my `customBindings.jaxb` file are two properties `schemaLocation` and `node`. Does property `schemaLocation` need to point at main WSDL or secondary WSDl? And does property `node` be exact path (XPath) to wanted complexType or is like this ok? And what is with namespaces within XPath (`node` property), it has to be `xs` or what? And what actually this `types` and `schema1` stands for in `schemaLocation`?

thx

Answer (score 0):

I came across your question while researching the same problem.

A few vague hints are found on this page: http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Dealing_with_errors.html

Causes for the "empty target node" message are suggested at the bottom of that page.